# Using httpclient 4.1 as a proxy within a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, proxy

We are writing a J2EE Java servlet which as a proxy between the browser client and another server.  We are using httpclient 4.1 code within a servlet, acting as a proxy between the browser request and the other server call.   Here is the main part of the question, httpclient 4.1 will return cookies that are used on the next set of requests, but it doesn't return the cookies as they are returned exactly from the server.  Is it possible to get the 'real' 'set-cookie' header information from the server within httpclient.

For example (here is pseudo code of the code that will set at the servlet level):

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
// Connect to another server //
List list = httpClient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
```

The list of cookies are (I believe) the cookies that are required for the next set of requests but not the exact representation of the cookies from the server.

For example, if the server responds with:

Set-Cookie: myval=;

...

In the list to the getCookies, the list is empty.  Because we are trying to create a proxy call, we don't want the list to be empty, we can to send myval=; from the servlet back to the browser client.

Is it possible to inject some kind of listener when httpclient processes a response?  Or does httpclient have an api call for all of the returned 'set-cookie' values?  Also, when connecting to the server, we may experience redirects, we will also want to collect all the set-cookie calls there as well.

Edit: Basically when making a request to another server with httpclient, and that call to httpclient includes redirects.  Is it possible to collect the cookie information along the redirect paths.

Comment: question, why aren't you using the servlet to redirect the request and retrieve the cookies?

Comment: It is really tied to the application use-case which involves making a request to an internal REST service.  The server connected between the servlet-httpclient code is not available on the internet.  Not available to the browser.

Comment: why cant you use RequestDispatcher to redirect the request? i am asking this because we have a similar use case where we need to read the cookies from an incoming request and then redirect it to a different servlet.

Comment: How would request dispatcher connect to other server with a different hostname?  Httpclient works fine under this scenario and the question is about httpclient.  Not the servlet/j2ee piece.

Comment: what about the `getHeader` or `getAllHeader`  method in CloseableHttpResponse? I'm working with HttpClient 4.4.1

Comment: That looks like what I might need, I will research those calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As cookies are set by using a header you can just extract the headers from the response directly and forward them:

Example using *http://bing.com* because it sets a bunch of cookies regardless of the user agent:

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://bing.com");
final HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
for(Header header: response.getHeaders("set-cookie")) {
    System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", header.getName(), header.getValue());
}
```

Output:

```
Set-Cookie: _FS=NU=1; domain=.bing.com; path=/
Set-Cookie: _HOP=; domain=.bing.com; path=/
Set-Cookie: _SS=SID=0E33DFF1E74942258D088E964991329D; domain=.bing.com; path=/
Set-Cookie: SRCHD=AF=NOFORM; expires=Fri, 11-Aug-2017 07:53:36 GMT; domain=.bing.com; path=/
Set-Cookie: SRCHUID=V=2&GUID=F9F751F2254D41AEBA076AF7737236E3; expires=Fri, 11-Aug-2017 07:53:36 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: SRCHUSR=AUTOREDIR=0&GEOVAR=&DOB=20150812; expires=Fri, 11-Aug-2017 07:53:36 GMT; domain=.bing.com; path=/
Set-Cookie: _EDGE_S=F=1&SID=1F7F788103616B0C246A708002856ABD; path=/; httponly; domain=bing.com
Set-Cookie: _EDGE_V=1; path=/; httponly; expires=Fri, 11-Aug-2017 07:53:36 GMT; domain=bing.com
Set-Cookie: MUID=3702A96D37A16DAA320AA16C36456C90; path=/; expires=Fri, 11-Aug-2017 07:53:36 GMT; domain=bing.com
Set-Cookie: MUIDB=3702A96D37A16DAA320AA16C36456C90; path=/; httponly; expires=Fri, 11-Aug-2017 07:53:36 GMT
```

Also, since you're running as a proxy it is probably a good idea to disable cookie management completely so you won't contaminate requests with cookies from different clients:

```
client.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.IGNORE_COOKIES);
```

**Update**:

Here's an example *RedirectStrategy* that stores all encountered *set-cookie* headers in the *HttpContext* - the *HttpContext* is the same for all redirects but not the same between invocations of *execute* - and then restores all of them on the final response:

```
public class CookieTrackingRedirectStrategy extends DefaultRedirectStrategy {

    @Override
    public boolean isRedirected(final HttpRequest request, final HttpResponse response, final HttpContext context) throws ProtocolException {
        boolean isRedirected = super.isRedirected(request, response, context);
        List<String> allCookies = (List<String>) context.getAttribute("all-cookies");
        if(isRedirected) {
            // Store cookies from this response for future restoration
            if(allCookies == null) {
                allCookies = new ArrayList<>();
                context.setAttribute("all-cookies", allCookies);
            }
            Header[] cookies = response.getHeaders("set-cookie");
            for(Header cookie : cookies) {
                allCookies.add(cookie.getValue());
            }
        } else if(allCookies != null) {
            // Restore all cookies to this response
            for(String cookie : allCookies) {
                response.addHeader("set-cookie", cookie);
            }
        }
        return isRedirected;
    }
}
```

Set it using *DefaultHttpClient.setRedirectStrategy*.

Comment: That is fine but won't collect all cookies with redirects.  If there are 10 redirects, you may end up printing out 0 cookies based on the last server request/response.

Comment: You can either disable automatic redirect handling and handle them yourself to get all the cookie headers or subclass the *DefaultRedirectStrategy* to intercept the response and collect the cookies before the redirect is handled.

Comment: I've added an example *RedirectStrategy* that uses the *HttpContext* to keep track of all cookies.